# Maven ArtifactNotFoundException troubleshooting

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers

**Problem:** I'm trying to get Google Protocol Buffers dependencies work. But with no result. Maven just can't pull any protocol buffers dependencies.

**Question1:** As I understand this dependency is absent in standard maven repositories, so I just need to indicate some extra repositories. *Am I right?*

**Question2:** *If answer to the first question is YES, than how can I get the url of that extra repository?* [Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0)  is the reference to maven dependency.

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] Plugin com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:0.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.google.protobuf.to
ols:maven-protoc-plugin:jar:0.3.2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the u
pdate interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:0.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resol
ved: Failure to find com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:jar:0.3.2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, res
olution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
       .......
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:jar:0.3.2 in http://rep
o.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or update
s are forced
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaSockets</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocExecutable>C:\Users\Clasik\Desktop\Java Sockets</protocExecutable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


        ......
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:jar:0.3.2 in http://repo.ma
ven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates ar
e forced   
  ...............
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841931/maven-protoc-plugin-configuration-in-pom-xml-incorrect

Comment: @FlorescentTicker they didn't provide an answer how to solve that with maven. They just propose to download the plugin manually. Moreover I've already solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing dependency is the [maven-protoc-plugin](http://sergei-ivanov.github.io/maven-protoc-plugin/), not protobuf-java. This plugin is [not available in Maven Central](https://github.com/sergei-ivanov/maven-protoc-plugin/issues/11).

According to it’s author you can add a self-hosted repository to the pom.xml:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>protoc-plugin</id>
        <url>http://sergei-ivanov.github.com/maven-protoc-plugin/repo/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

But I’m only getting a 404 here. So you can either contact the author or check out the sources and install the plugin manually in your local repository.

Comment: should I include some proto buffers' sources besides plugin\dependencies definition in pom.xml? When I try `mvn clean install` I get `cannot find symbol` errors, like `MessageOrBuilder`, `Parser` etc. As I understand that are protocol buffer libraries

Comment: Are you working with dtrott’s or ivanov’s version now? Please compare with the according documentation. Dtrott is using protobuf-java in Version 2.3.0 for instance. Maybe 2.5.0 brought incompatible changes. (Just a guess…)

Comment: I've already switched to ivanov version. What should I do. May be it'll be better if I post my demo on GitHub and you'll what is going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve no idea what this plugin is doing. I just could tell you why maven didn’t find the plugin.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this, the <pluginRepositories>...</pluginRepositories> snippet in answer does work even though you get a 404 when trying to access it with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add plugin repository:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>dtrott</id>
        <url>http://maven.davidtrott.com/repository</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: There you will only find version 0.1.10. The configured version 0.3.2 is coming from [this fork](https://github.com/sergei-ivanov/maven-protoc-plugin)

Comment: @lefloh as I understand you propose to change `pluginRepository` definition. May you provide your version in separate answer please?

Comment: I already answered. But problem is that the maven-repository for the fork seems to be down.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of this plugin are available from Bintray:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>protoc-plugin</id>
    <url>https://dl.bintray.com/sergei-ivanov/maven</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I was able to get version 0.3.2 using this plugin repository which is linked to in the project [readme](https://github.com/sergei-ivanov/maven-protoc-plugin)